# Where can I buy pants?

Tags: dark-souls-3

In previous Souls games, there is usually at least 1 vendor in the hub area. I've read online that the Handmaiden fills this role in Dark Souls 3 and sells all kinds of useful things, including garments to cover my lower body. But I've run around Firelink for an obscenely long time without being able to find her.

**Where is the Handmaiden?**

*Seriously, this loincloth is getting real drafty and no enemies are dropping pants.*

Comment: It took me a disturbing amount of time to find this on my own.

Comment: I'm just dropping this here... http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/a/ab/Not_On_My_Clothes_2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120912202532

Comment: All I want is some pants. A decent pair of pants.

Comment: If your enemies were dropping pants on a regular basis, you'd probably want a loincloth to save time... but I don't think Dark Souls 3 is that kind of game...

Comment: @twobugs Solomon Grundy want pants, too!

Comment: At the pants-store.

Comment: Year 2018 and I read this question, what in the serious blasphemy are you talking about! Is the guy actually serious?! O wait, I cant even find a plank shield....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the Handmaiden NPC is in Firelink Shrine but she is very hard to see. She can be found between the central bonfire and the blacksmith. She's an older woman in dark robes seated in a small hallway. She sells consumables, weapons, armor, and spells (two sorceries and a miracle). She is available from the start of the game.

*And she carries a pair of pants.*

Comment: @Sterno She gets more things that she'll sell as the game goes on.